# Extending a linearly independent set to a basis (without matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I make an exercise in the book "Linear Algebra Done Right

Exercise 2.B (4)

Let $U$ be subspace of $\mathbb Cˆ5$ defined by:

$U:=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3,z_4,z_5) \in \ \mathbb Cˆ5: 6z_1=z_2 \ \text{and} \ z_3+2z_4+3z_5=0\}$

a) Find a basis

b) Extend the basis in part (a) to a basis of $\mathbb Cˆ5$.

a) I found the basis $v_1=(1,6,0,0,0), v_2=(0,0,-2,1,0), v_3=(0,0,-3,0,1)$.

b) Now I have to extend it to basis of $\mathbb Cˆ5$

I got the vectors $v_4=(0,1,0,0,0),v_5=(0,1,0,1,0)$. How did I find it? Well, I used the theorem, that new vectors must not be in span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, then they will be linearly independent and therefore a basis. For example $v_4$ is not in span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ because $v_1$ with the first two coordinates has form $6a,a$ with this form I will never get my $v_4$ and the first two coordinates of $v_2,v_3$ are equal 0 so they play no role. Moreover the vectors $v_4=(1,0,0,0,0), v_5=(0,0,1,0,1)$ will also work by the same logic. So I found many vectors, that will work.

$\textbf{The question is:}$ How can I choose the vectors to extend the basis? I mean, choose the vectors without thinking in my head, whether this vector is in span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ or not. I think it's somehow connected with that $z_1,z_4,z_5$ are independent variables, but I can't understand how? So what has my choice of linearly independent vectors to do with independent variables $z_1,z_4,z_5$?

Please, don't tell about matrix, I want to understand this structure, not just adding the vectors in matrix)

Comment: I am confused by your requirement - the simplest and most concise way to extend a given linearly independent set would be to use language of matrices and row reductions etc. If you insist on not using any matrix, then there is no better way than just what you did - which is more or less looking at the vectors individually and see if there is an obvious guess, which there was for your example.

Comment: @dezdichado that’s because I didn’t have matrices in my book yet, they will come later, therefore I am not sure, that I can use it.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are working in ${\bf C}^{5}$ then $\dim_{{\bf C}}({\bf C}^5)=5$, and this means that you need $5$ linearly independent vectors spanning the vector space. But you know, $3$ linearly independent vectors now by $a)$ so you only have to worry about adding $2$ more linearly independent vectors to complete a basis of the vector space. Of course, you can choose many, as long as they are linearly independent. For the latter, one prefers to always add vectors from a canonical basis of vector space.

**Edit:**

I will give a way to respond the question: *"how can we extend a basis?"*. In order to stay close to the question in the post, let's consider a vector space $V$ of dimension $5$ and a subspace $U$ of $V$ with dimension $3$, where a basis given by $B=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is known. We can set up the following algorithm to extend $B$ to a base of $V$.

Steps:

1. Write a canonical basis of $V$, let's say the set $B'=\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3},e_{4},e_{5}\}$.
2. Take $e_{1}\in B$, then write $e_{1}$ as a linear combination of vectors of the vectors in $B$.
3. If the system given in step 2 is inconsistent (linear dependence is not possible), then we make $B\gets B\cup \{e_{1}\}$. If the system given in step 2 is consistent (linear dependence is possible), we do not perform the above set-operation and we do not update $B$.
4. Take $e_{2}\in B$ and repeat step 2 and then step 3.
5. The process repeat-continues until a base for $V$ has been find by extension of $B$.

In words:

Take a vector of $B'$ and see if it is a linear combination of the vectors in $B$. If the answer is "no", add the vector (extend the basis) to $B$. If the answer is "yes", ignore that vector. The process continues in the same way until it completes a basis for $V$ by extension of $B$.

Example:

Let's do this with your example.

Steps:

1. Write $B'=\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,1)\}$ a basis for ${\bf C}^{5}$.
2. Setting $(1,0,0,0,0)=\alpha_{1}(1,6,0,0,0)+\alpha_{2}(0,0,-2,1,0)+\alpha_{3}(0,0,-3,0,1)$.
3. The linear system $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\6&0&0\\0&-2&-3\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1}\\ \alpha_{2}\\ \alpha_{3}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $ is incosistent. Thus we update $B=\{(1,6,0,0,0),(0,0,-2,1,0),(0,0,-3,0,1),(1,0,0,0,0)\}$.
4. Setting $(0,1,0,0,0)=\alpha_{1}(1,6,0,0,0)+\alpha_{2}(0,0,-2,1,0)+\alpha_{3}(0,0,-3,0,1)+\alpha_{4}(1,0,0,0,0)$, then the linear system $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\6&0&0&0\\0&-2&-3&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1}\\ \alpha_{2}\\ \alpha_{3}\\ \alpha_{4}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $ is cosistent. Thus we do not update $B$.
5. Setting $(0,0,1,0,0)=\alpha_{1}(1,6,0,0,0)+\alpha_{2}(0,0,-2,1,0)+\alpha_{3}(0,0,-3,0,1)+\alpha_{4}(1,0,0,0,0)$, then the linear system $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1\\6&0&0&0\\0&-2&-3&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{1}\\ \alpha_{2}\\ \alpha_{3}\\ \alpha_{4}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} $ is incosistent.  Thus we update $B=\{(1,6,0,0,0),(0,0,-2,1,0),(0,0,-3,0,1),(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0)\}$.
6. The process ends because ${\rm card}(B)=5=\dim_{{\bf C}}({\bf C}^{5})$. Therefore, we find
   $$B^{*}=\{(1,6,0,0,0),(0,0,-2,1,0),(0,0,-3,0,1),(1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0)\}$$
   as a basis for ${\bf C}^{5}$ found by extension of the basis found for the subspace $U$.

All of the above is basically an application of the replacement theorem. Of course, you can simplify steps or work with the notion of rank. But that is one way to answer your question. I hope this is more clear, now.

Comment: Thank you, but It was not answer to my question. My question is: what has my choice of linearly independent vectors to do with independent variables $z_1,z_4,z_5$?

Comment: There is not problem. Your first question was "How can I choose the vectors to extend the basis?" My answer was: in preference add linearly independent vectors of a canonical basis of the space.

Comment: You don't have to worry if they are spanning. Your concern should be in the linear independence of the vectors. This is because we know that: If $\dim V=n$, then any linearly independent subset of $V$ that contains exactly $n$ vectors is a basis for $V$.

Comment: But if I choose the vectors, which are not in span, they are automatically linearly independent.) Ok, you suggest to add two linearly independent vectors $v_4,v5$. But it can be, that $v_1,...v_5$ are linearly dependent. So how can I choose this 2 vectors $v_4,v_5$ such that they are all $v_1,..v_5$ linearly independent?

Comment: Well, that was exactly my answer: we can always try to complete a basis using vectors of a canonical basis. A canonical basis for ${\bf C}^{5}$ is given by $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5\}$ with $e_{i}\in {\bf C}^{5}$. So, we can try for example with $e_3=(0,0,1,0)$ and $e_4=(0,0,0,1)$ and if they fail in independence, you try others and that's it.

Comment: So, u suggest just by trying? I think there is here something more interesting) How we can do it)

Comment: Well, I suggest that indeed, but I suggest the way to choose them as well. What I indicate has its roots in the "replacement  theorem". Also, two vectors are independent linearly iff they are not dependent linearly. But dependence linear means find a scalar $k$ such that $v=kw$. This is useful in these types of problems. You can't help but think, math is about thinking. I'm sorry that my answer was not what you were looking for, maybe another user can provide you with an answer in the closest order to the one you requested.

Comment: I'm sorry, A.P., but this is not an answer. Needed but not included here is *how* do you find a vector linearly independent to the others so far to add to your basis. -1

Comment: @Mike Thank you for the negative vote with your respective feedback. This allows me to improve, sure. I'll try to improve my answer, now I'm at work.

Comment: I have updated my post to try to answer the question fully. Please let me know if there is anything I still need to improve or correct, I'll keep an eye on it.